# Postgresql 10: How to move 4 existing columns to an array column

Tags: arrays, postgresql-10

I have the following table called client:

```
 Table "public.client"
       Column        |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |           Default            
---------------------+---------+-----------+----------+------------------------------
 clientid            | integer |           | not null | generated always as identity
 account_name        | text    |           | not null | 
 last_name           | text    |           |          | 
 first_name          | text    |           |          | 
 address             | text    |           | not null | 
 suburbid            | integer |           |          | 
 cityid              | integer |           |          | 
 post_code           | integer |           | not null | 
 business_phone      | text    |           |          | 
 home_phone          | text    |           |          | 
 mobile_phone        | text    |           |          | 
 alternative_phone   | text    |           |          | 
 email               | text    |           |          | 
 quote_detailsid     | integer |           |          | 
 invoice_typeid      | integer |           |          | 
 payment_typeid      | integer |           |          | 
 job_typeid          | integer |           |          | 
 communicationid     | integer |           |          | 
 accessid            | integer |           |          | 
 difficulty_levelid  | integer |           |          | 
 current_lawn_price  | numeric |           |          | 
 square_meters       | numeric |           |          | 
 note                | text    |           |          | 
 client_statusid     | integer |           |          | 
 reason_for_statusid | integer |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "client_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (clientid)
    "account_name_check" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (account_name)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "client_accessid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (accessid) REFERENCES access(accessid)
    "client_cityid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (cityid) REFERENCES city(cityid)
    "client_client_statusid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (client_statusid) REFERENCES client_status(client_statusid)
    "client_communicationid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (communicationid) REFERENCES communication(communicationid)
    "client_difficulty_levelid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (difficulty_levelid) REFERENCES difficulty_level(difficulty_levelid)
    "client_invoice_typeid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (invoice_typeid) REFERENCES invoice_type(invoice_typeid)
    "client_job_typeid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (job_typeid) REFERENCES job_type(job_typeid)
    "client_payment_typeid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (payment_typeid) REFERENCES payment_type(payment_typeid)
    "client_quote_detailsid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (quote_detailsid) REFERENCES quote_details(quote_detailsid)
    "client_reason_for_statusid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (reason_for_statusid) REFERENCES reason_for_status(reason_for_statusid)
    "client_suburbid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (suburbid) REFERENCES suburb(suburbid)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "work" CONSTRAINT "work_clientid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (clientid) REFERENCES client(clientid)
```

I want to move all phone columns (business_phone, home_phone, mobile_phone, alternative_phone) as an array to one column called phone_numbers and get rid of the four phone_columns. Any idea how to do this safely without losing any records?

Comment: And how are you going to distinguish those four phone numbers after that? if you really think you need to combine them into one column, I would rather use a `jsonb` column where the numbers are stored as key/value pairs

Comment: How could that be done with jsonb. Sorry I am not familiar with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the array column.

```
ALTER TABLE client
ADD COLUMN phone_numbers text[];
```

Then use an UPDATE command to set the value of the array column based on the other four.

```
UPDATE client
SET phone_numbers = [business_phone,home_phone,mobile_phone,alternate_phone]; -- test and modify if needed
```

You can repeat this UPDATE as many times as it takes to get it right.  Then you can safely DROP the four old columns.

```
ALTER TABLE client
DROP COLUMN business_phone
DROP COLUMN home_phone
DROP COLUMN mobile_phone
DROP COLUMN alternate_phone;
```